# What is the difference between Bazel toolchain_vanilla and java_toolchain?

Tags: bazel

Bazel has multiple different *toolchains* to support compilation of Java code. They are configurable with command line arguments:

```
--java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:toolchain_vanilla
--java_toolchain=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:java_toolchain11
```

Based on some hints in GitHub issues or commit comments I was able to figure out that the "*vanilla*" toolchain is more bare bone and seems to work better with newer/latest JDK versions. It seems that it misses the ErrorProne compiler. However, it's unclear what *other* features I'll miss by using the *vanilla* toolchain vs. the *regular* toolchain.

The documentation is that area is sparse.
Is there a good comparison between both toolchain, i.e. what toolchain triggers which behavior in Bazel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found *some* hints [buried in Bazel source code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/4.2.1/tools/jdk/BUILD#L388).

```
# The 'vanilla' toolchain is an unsupported alternative to the default.
#
# It does not provider any of the following features:
#   * Error Prone
#   * Strict Java Deps
#   * Header Compilation
#   * Reduced Classpath Optimization
#
# It uses the version of javac from the `--host_javabase` instead of the
# embedded javac, which may not be source- or bug-compatible with the embedded
# javac.
#
# However it does allow using a wider range of `--host_javabase`s, including
# versions newer than the current embedded JDK.
```

I don't know if this is the complete story. But it looks like the *vanilla* toolchain has some significant disadvantages especially with missing header compilation.

Comment: Where did you find the comment that you are citing? I tried your link but could not find the text.

Comment: I fixed the link. Apparently, the comment has been removed in the latest version of the file.